# Garbage data when running this program (Student record program)

Tags: c++

First off this is my own code, not copied.

The program is supposed to read student data from a "grades.txt" file which has marks for quizzes, finals etc and calculate the average, assign grades, and write the names and grades students who have passed and failed to "pass.txt" and "fail.txt". 
Now the issue I face is that the total amount of students is 57. The program does stuff correctly for up to 39 students but it's always garbage values after that :(

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>


using namespace std;
int counter; //counts the number of students

struct STUDENT
{
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
    long idnumber;
    int quiz1;   //10%
    int quiz2;   //10%
    int mid1;   //15%
    int mid2;   //15%
    double homework;   //10%
    double Final;      //40%
    double average; //to be calculated
    char grade;  //to be calculated
};
void Stcounter()
{

    ifstream thing ("Grades.txt");
    string dummy;
    getline(thing,dummy);                    //for skipping the first line

    string line;
    int b=0;
    while(getline(thing, line))
        b++;
        counter=b;
        cout<<"Total number of students is  "<< counter<<endl;
}
void read( STUDENT record[57])
{
    float a;
        ifstream thing("Grades.txt");
string d;
getline(thing,d);

     for(int i=0;i<56;i++)
    {
      if( thing>> record[i].idnumber>>record[i].firstname>>record[i].lastname>>record[i].quiz1>>record[i].quiz2>>record[i].mid1>>record[i].mid2>>record[i].homework>>record[i].Final)

   a=(record[i].quiz1/10)+(record[i].quiz2/10)+((record[i].mid1*15)/100)+((record[i].mid2*15)/100)+(record[i].homework/10)+((record[i].Final*40)/100);
   record[i].average=a;
   if(a>=85)
   {
       record[i].grade='A';

   }
   else if(a>=70)
   {
       record[i].grade='B';

   }
   else if(a>=55)
   {
       record[i].grade='C';

   }
   else if(a>=40)
   {
       record[i].grade='D';

   }
   else
   {
       record[i].grade='F';

   }
    }

}
void  WriteToFile (STUDENT record[57])
{
    ofstream p, f;
    p.open("Pass.txt");
    f.open("Fail.txt");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 56; i++)
    {
        if (record[i].average >= 40)
        {
            p << record[i].idnumber << " " << record[i].firstname << " " << record[i].lastname << "  passed with grade " << record[i].grade <<endl;
        }
        else
            f << record[i].idnumber << " " << record[i].firstname << " " << record[i].lastname << "  has failed"<<endl;
    }
    p.close();
    f.close();
}
//This function counts how many students got a certain grade
void gradecount(STUDENT record[57])
{
    int c1=0,c2=0,c3=0,c4=0,c5=0;
    for(int i=0;i<57;i++)
    {
        if (record[i].grade=='A')
            c1++;
        else if(record[i].grade=='B')
            c2++;
        else if(record[i].grade=='C')
            c3++;
            else if(record[i].grade=='D')
            c4++;
            else
                c5++;

    }
    cout<<c1<<" students got A"<<endl;
    cout<<c2<<" students got B"<<endl;
    cout<<c3<<" students got C"<<endl;
    cout<<c4<<" students got D"<<endl;
    cout<<c5<<" students got F"<<endl;
}


int main()
{
    STUDENT record[57];
    read(record);
    WriteToFile (record);
    Stcounter();
    gradecount(record);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you try stepping through the code with debugger?

Comment: I highly recommend you use `std::vector` instead of an array.  They are easier to manage and pass to functions.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius I did. I'm using CodeBlocks as my IDE and also used the updated version of DevC++ (By Orwell). It's not showing any errors

Comment: @Mr.Meeseeks You didn't read my comment. Re-read it again. Debugger, on its own, shouldn't show any errors. It's a tool, used to step-through your application. If you did step-through it - you would've found the issue on your own.

Comment: If you only have 57 records in the input file, and hardcoded your program to read 80, then the last 23 elements in your array will be incorrect. You need to check for end of the file and keep track of the size, at least if you want to continue to use arrays instead of `std::vector`.

Comment: @thomas-matthews Sorry but it's required that arrays be used. I'm not doing this for myself. I'm helping a friend with her assignment.

Comment: Oh, and you should really take some time to [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude So the array size should be the same as the number of students? And sorry if my question isn't concise, it's my first time on the website.

Comment: The size could be smaller, or larger, as long as you keep track of the *actual* number of records read. And to do that you need to return the number of records from the `read` function. And you need to handle end-of-file (and error) checking *properly*.

Comment: @Algirdas Preidžius Thanks, I'll do that.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I used the getline function to get the total number of lines/students and it gives the correct answer of 57. I then used that variable to run the loop while keeping the array size the same [80] but it still messes up the student records. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? I used eof() too but people said getline() is a better alternative.

Comment: If you use `getline` (either version) you will have a *string* and not an integer value. You do convert the string into an integer value?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thank you so much for your help so far. I've included that new code in the middle it's inside the Stcounter() function, I'm using a dummy string to skip the header line inside the grades.txt file. I tried using the total number of students as the condition for the for loops but that still won't work, so I kept the array size the same as the amount of students. My problem now is how do I use arraysize of 80 and still have the program run correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you didnt notice in your if statement

```
float a;
if(beggar>>record[i].idnumber>>record[i].firstname>>record[i].lastname>>record[i].quiz1>>record[i].quiz2>>record[i].mid1>>record[i].mid2>>record[i].homework>>record[i].Final)
    a=(record[i].quiz1/10)+(record[i].quiz2/10)+((record[i].mid1*15)/100)+((record[i].mid2*15)/100)+(record[i].homework/10)+((record[i].Final*40)/100);
record[i].average=a;
```

it is giving you an error that you used the variable 'a' without it being initialized. So just when you declare a as a float assign it to 0 or something else

Comment: I'm not facing any build errors, if that's what you're trying to say.